# Can I read numbers one by one from a single-line string in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, input

There is a task:

- In the first line quantity of numbers N(0 < N < 40000) is entered from a keyboard;
- In the second line a sequence of numbers ending with "0" is entered from a keyboard.
- In the second line will be entered all numbers from 1 to N except one.
- I should print them in ascending order.
- Program must be memory effective which means used memory should not be depended on quantity of numbers in the second line.

Sample input:

```
5
3 5 1 4 0
```

Sample output:

```
1 3 4 5
```

By task conditions I should not use lists or save the whole second line in a variable like

```
input = input()
```

or

```
a = []
a = input().split()
```

Now I don't know how to solve this task using Python 3.x. The problem is how to treat the second line of the input without saving it into memory? I wrote a program that will work if numbers in the second line are entered in separate lines like this:

```
5
3
5
1
4
0
```

This is my program:

```py
N = int(input())
num, sum = -1, 0
while num:
    num = int(input())
    sum += t
num = int((N + 1) * N / 2) - sum 
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    if i != num:
        print(i, end = ' ')
```

As only one number can be missed, I calculate a sum of numbers entered from the keyboard and sum of numbers from 1 to N. The difference between the sums is that missed number which I do not print in answer. Well, this code is not working with the input style from task conditions. For me that become a surprise! As I remember in C++ you could easily handle this task(by the way this problem is from my school exam where you may write a code in any language so the difficulties are only in Python) with a code like this:

```cpp
while (num) {
  std::cin >> num;
  sum += num;
}
```

And it would not be depended on how do you enter the numbers.
So I want to ask you if there are any ways to overcome this problem of stepwise reading one-line input wihtout saving it in memory in general and solve my task using school knowledge in particular.(the second part is unnecessary if the first is answered)

In the internet I find that input() ends with a newline symbol by default. May be this can be changed?

Comment: Why can't you save it as a variable?  What are these "rules" you refer to?  How are you reading these numbers in the first place if they are not in a variable?

Comment: What do you plan to do next with those numbers?

Comment: Are these numbers input from the keyboard or a file?

Comment: gallen, yes. revliscano, I should find which numbers from 1 to n are not in this order. Rocket Hazmat, the first number(and the first line) is the quantity of numbers in the next line.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, this is  one of the tasks from my exam which I’m preparing to now. The rules requires to use constant amount of memory regardless of a quantity of numbers in the line.
(Don’t pay attention to the previous answer to you - I just forget what you have asked me about)

Comment: @trxxxxkov I was going to post an answer, but then the question got closed. My primary suggestion is this: use a python generator that yields the current number either from STDIN or a file object, depending on where the data is coming from.

Comment: @trxxxxkov So, I'm guessing it's some sort of a stream?

Comment: @Paul M. I rewrite the question. I hope it become more clear now. Can you show me how to 'yield the current number from STDIN' please? By the way can you tell me if my question was raised when I edited it or I'll have to create a new one in 24h?

Comment: @PaulM. Can you provide your suggestion in code?

Comment: @trxxxxkov Thanks for editing your question with more detail. I've voted to reopen your question so that more answers can be accepted, but you'll need three votes in total to reopen your question. I would share some code with you, but it's inconvenient to fit it in a comment, so I'll wait until the question gets reopened.

Answer (score 0):

input multiline, and end after `-1` input

```py
list(iter(input, '-1'))
```